# Add child to specific node

Tags: php, xml, dom

Let's say i have already a XML file which i load like this:

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$domtree->load('test.xml');
```

The XML file has a structure like this:

```
<software>
    <info>
        <version>6.3</version>
    </info>
    <some_stuff>
        <test1>
            <somedata>adsd</somedata>
        </test1>
    </some_stuff>
</software>
```

How can i add a new element to the decryption?

I tried:

```
$some_stuff = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('software');
$some_stuff = $some_stuff->getElementsByTagName('some_stuff');
$funcgroup = $some_stuff->appendChild($domtree->createElement('test2'));
```

PHP Error:

```
Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: I was on the wrong solution...

`$domtree` is your object. You cannot set `$some_stuff` to it's value and use it as an object. This is why your getting the undefined method error.

This code will work (although it doesn't quite achieve what you want I think):

```
$domtree->loadXML(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
$some_stuff = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('software');
$some_stuff = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('some_stuff');
$funcgroup = $domtree->appendChild($domtree->createElement('test2'));
```

Note how I'm referencing the `$domtree` object in each line and not the variables you are setting.

Comment: Then i get: `Undefined property: DOMNodeList::$documentElement`

Answer (score 1):

This code will work

```
$domtree  = new \DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
            $xmlfile    = "test.xml";
            $domtree->load($xmlfile);
            $xml_stuff          = $domtree->getElementsByTagName('some_stuff')-> item(0) ;
            $xmlNode1           = $domtree->createElement('test2');
            $xmlNode1           = $xml_stuff->appendChild($xmlNode1);
            $domtree->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $domtree->FormatOutput=true;
            $domtree->saveXML();
            $domtree->save($xmlfile);
```